# how to select rows when minute value change

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named

```
Ship(Date datetime,name varchar(50),Type char(1)).
```

In table Ship The "Date" Column is of datetime datatype. I want to select rows from ship table when minute value in Date column (of Datetime datatype) changes. For this i used the following query:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT Name, Date,Type, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date desc)
  FROM Ship
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE rn = 1
```

But the desired output is not coming. The Result coming is:

```
Date                         Name     Type

2017-05-08 14:59:13.000      sumit      A
2017-05-08 14:59:23.000      sumit      B
2017-05-08 14:59:33.000      sumit      A
2017-05-08 15:00:05.000      Ajay       B
2017-05-08 15:00:13.000      Deep       G
2017-05-08 15:01:03.000     Suri        D   
2017-05-08 15:01:13.000     Faiz        E
```

Here in above output those rows are also coming when there is a change in second value of Date column. But i want to select rows when there is change in minute value of Date  Column.Can anyone solve this?

Comment: please add sample data and expected outcome

Comment: What does `select rows from ship table when minute value in Date column changes` mean?. As in when someone updates the row with a new minute value? Or when its changed from (perhaps) the previous record

Comment: my question edited.

Comment: Can anyone solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `datediff minute` on `partition by` clause

```
;WITH x AS
(
 SELECT Name, Date,Type, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
 (PARTITION BY datediff(min,0,[Date]) ORDER BY Date desc)
 FROM Ship
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE rn = 1
```

Or it is shorter version

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
      Name, Date,Type
FROM Ship
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY datediff(min,0,[Date]) ORDER BY [date] desc)
```

Comment: It really works when minute value changes bur how can we do it when Type changes?

Comment: What is the problem with Type change? You want partition by minute change and Type, right? Please edit your question, provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the **DATEPART** in the `PARTITION BY` to get the change in the minutes section only.

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT Name, Date,Type, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY DATEPART(N, Date) ORDER BY Date desc)
  FROM Ship
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE rn = 1
```

Refer the Demo: http://rextester.com/YZW84894

Comment: It is not correct for using datepart. For example the same minute but different hour.